# Recipe for target 'curve25519-donna-c64.o" failed

Tags: python-3.x, gcc, raspberry-pi, elliptic-curve, curve-25519

I have a problem trying to compile a library. I am using curve25519-donna to generate key pairs. I have already downloaded the library and unzipped the file, but my problem is with the compilation.

I have changed my directory to curve25519-donna-1.3 and this is the code I tried to use the compile the library:

```
env CC='gcc -02' make
```

And this was the outcome.

```
Makefile:23 recipe for target 'curve25519-donna-c64.o' failed
make: *** [curve25519-donna-c64.o] Error 1
```

I am running on a Raspberry pi OS, am I missing some gcc's that I need to install in this operating system? 
I've upgraded and updated but I am still having problems with this. Any help will be much appreciated, thanks!!